# Javascript nested function losing scope

Tags: javascript, binding, scope

Can someone explains the scope binding of the following code please

```
window.name = "window";

object = {
       name: "object",
       method: function() {
             nestedMethod: function() {
                   console.log(this.name);
             }
             nestedMethod();
       }
}

object.method();  // print 'window'
```

I think my question is more about `this`...why is `this` losing the scope and default to the global scope ? do all the anonymous functions that we created will go on the global scope ?

Comment: You can try using the name of the object, so `object.name`.

Comment: no. all functions go on the global scope by default, unless bound to object as a property...

Comment: @dandavis that is really inaccurate. Functions don't inherently "go on" any scope at all. The value of `this` is determined by the circumstances of each call to a function.

Comment: It prints `"object"` for me when I try it in node.js (once I put a `;` after the assignment to `object`).

Comment: @Pointy: i was attempting to put it in terms familiar to the OP...

Comment: @dandavis ok, fair enough :) It's really common for Java or C++ or C# programmers to get really confused about the relationship between JavaScript functions and objects, especially when functions are defined as property values in object literals.

Comment: `nestedMethod: function() {` looks like a label, not a variable or function name. Anyways, [learn about `this` from the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you call a function, simply by writing `func()`, `this` inside the function will point to the global object. In your case you write:

```
nestedMethod();
```

So `this` inside `nestedMethod` is the window object. You can use `call` (or `apply`) to manually define a context for you function call:

```
nestedMethod.call(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
window.name = "window";

object = {
    name: "object",
    method: function () {
        var self = this;
        var nestedMethod = function () {
            console.log(self.name); // or object.name without declaring self
        }
        nestedMethod();
    }
}

object.method(); // print 'object'
```

Save the scope of the object - or use the object itself!

> do all the anonymous functions that we created will go on the global scope ?

No, not all the **anonymous functions** lose their scope, **all the functions** scopes are bound to the global object(if they are not called with specific `this`, see `apply` and `call`, see the example below)!

```
window.name = "window";

object = {
    name: "object",
    method: function () {
        var nestedMethod = function () {
            console.log(this.name);
        }
        nestedMethod.call(this); //change the this arg in the current object scope
        // when you call this function with .call(this) you are changing the value of the nestedMethod's this to the current this, which is object
    }
}

object.method(); // print 'object'
```

Comment: what do you mean all the functions are scoped to the global object ? are you saying i can directly call nestedMethod on global scope ?

Comment: FYI, referring to `this` as *scope* is incorrect (at least it seems to me that you are doing that).

Comment: _"all the functions are scoped to the global object"_ -- I think this is a bit inaccurate. Functions where `this` is not bound, will run in the context of window, but the scope will still be the closest function.

Comment: My bad, already edited. Anyway @elclanrs that's not totally true, `this` changes to the global scope even if we use `.call(thisArg)`, where `thisArg` is defined as `null` or `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

*Any* function that's invoked like this:

```
someFunction();
```

will have the global scope as the value of `this` (in non-strict mode). You can either stash the outer scope in a local variable, or else use `.call()` or `.apply()`:

```
  nestedMethod.call(this);
```

Comment: You mean any function invoked like that no matter which scope that it's being called and where it's being defined ?

Comment: @user1389813 yes, that's correct. Any function that's simply invoked (not with `.call()` or `.apply()`, not with `new`, and not via an object property reference like `foo.myFunc()`) will result in the value of `this` being the `window` (global) object in non-strict mode, and `undefined` in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

you should declare nested function like this:

```
Super.prototype.someFunc = function() {
  this.nestedFunc = function() {}
  //now call it
  this.nestedFunc()
}
```