# Why doesn't calling this server method work in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

I have a file called authServices.coffee in the server/server directory of my Meteor project. It has the following function definition, followed by a `Meteor.methods` call:

```
 isAuthorized = () ->
    # note that at this point there is ever to be but one authorized user
    authorized = Assets.getText('authorizedUsers').trim()
    this.userId.trim() is authorized
```

This does not work--that is, calling `Meteor.call 'getKey'` returns `undefined`

```
Meteor.methods(
    isAuthorized : isAuthorized
    getKey : () -> 
    if isAuthorized()
        Assets.getText('Key')
)
```

but if I inline the `isAuthorized` within the above `getKey`, it returns `true` (given the correct input)

I'm guessing this is a function of how `this` behaves for these objects, but can't quite get a handle on it.

Comment: Don't you have to use Meteor.userId instead of this.userId anywhere other than publish functions and methods?

Comment: in changing `this` to `Meteor.userId` in `authorizedUsers` I get `throw new Error("Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions."); // 17`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `isAuthorized`, and the method `getKey` have different contexts. The easiest solution is just to implement `getKey` like so:

```
getKey: ->
  if Meteor.call 'isAuthorized'
    Assets.getText 'Key'
```

Alternatively you could manually use `call` or `apply` to pass `this`, or you could pass `@userId` as a parameter to the `isAuthorized` function.

Style point: when using CS, you don't need the empty parens when your function takes no arguments.

Comment: I don't _need_ 'em... but it looks better with 'em.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be an option?

```
isAuthorized = (userId) ->
    # note that at this point there is ever to be but one authorized user
    authorized = Assets.getText('authorizedUsers').trim()
    userId.trim() is authorized

Meteor.methods(
    isAuthorized : () -> 
        isAuthorized(this.userId)
    getKey : () -> 
        if isAuthorized(this.userId)
            Assets.getText('Key')
)
```

Comment: yes, that's actually where I ended up in terms of implementation. I'm looking for a good explanation of `this` and how it behaves here.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558635/javascript-nested-function-losing-scope).